# request active storage image show only one not all images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

As Rookie Rails, i am able to get all images to display on the html.erb as using model as   `has_many_attached :images`

but i have tried many different way like this code below

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <% if @tool.images.attached? %>
            <% @tool.images.each do |image| %>
                <div class="img-fluid <%= 'active' if image.id == @images[0].id %>">
                  <%= link_to image_tag(image), image %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

but didn't show one image but only a few images as I am trying to fix this

```
image.id == @images[0].id
```

this code is dont display one image, do you know where i can use this code into this as i have tried many way but all failed

if i use this code

```
<!-- Image -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <% if @tool.images.attached? %>
        <% @tool.images.each do |image| %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(image, class:"tools-gallery"), image %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

it show fine and able to get displayed

[image]

but I don't want two images or more, it ok for the gallery but not this pages as it need show one image.

and the controller.rb

```
  def show
    @images = @tool.images
  end
```

Comment: Do you wan't only the first image?

Comment: i want to get only one image on the page, so i have page for gallery which that fine, but this page i want just one image show on this page, so this ID have 3 or 4 images so i want get just one image from this ID images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= image_tag @tool.images.first if @tool.images.attached? %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks you make sound it so easy, look like i put it too complex code make everything gone wrong